# aspectJ + gradle как запускать?

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj

Пытаюсь подключить и протестировать aspectJ.
Необходимо использовать его без Spring.
Сборщик - Gradle 5.
Среда разработки - IDEA

Изучил множество примеров на git но ни один не заработал как я полагал.
Возможно, что я как то не так его запускаю, но не пойму как еще это можно сделать.
Я запускаю задачу jar (хотя перепробовал уже все).
Если запустить полученный jar, то будет сообщение о том, что нет манифеста. Если добавить в `build.gradle`

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'ru.MyClass.MyClass'
    }
}
```

То проект запускается, но не отрабатывают аспекты.

Мой проект https://github.com/FilatovDA/aspectJ_test.git

Как правильно запустить такой проект, что бы получить jar с работающими аспектами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, есть проблема с `fat-jar`, которая будет строить дерево зависимостей.
Попробуйте данный вариант:

```java
jar {
    manifest {
        // This is where the Main class is specified for launching applications (otherwise the jar will not start)
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'ru.MyClass.MyClass'
    }

    // Create fat-jar file
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало!